# join user id from tblB to user from tblA and get username

Tags: mysql, sql

how to join userid to user and get the username ?
I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac600/1

```
   CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
user varchar(255),
 category int(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblB
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
username varchar(255),
 userid int(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO tblA (user, category ) VALUES
('1', '1'),
('1', '2'),
('1', '3'),
('1', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('3', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('4', '1'),
('4', '1'),
('2', '1');


INSERT INTO tblB (userid, username ) VALUES
('1', 'A'),
('2', 'B'),
('3', 'C'),
('4', 'D'),
('5', 'E');
```

query:

```
SELECT
  groups.*,
  @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
FROM
  (select 
    user,
    category,
    count(*) as num
  from 
    tblA
  where 
    category=1 
  group by 
    user, 
    category
  order by 
    num desc,
    user) AS groups
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank:=0) AS init
```

the table looks like :

```
username    category    num Ascending   rank    
B   1   6   2
A   1   2   1
D   1   2   4
C   1   1   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN`, for example:

```
SELECT
  tblB.username,
  groups.*,
  @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
FROM
  (select 
    user,
    category,
    count(*) as num
  from 
    tblA
  where 
    category=1 
  group by 
    user, 
    category
  order by 
    num desc,
    user) AS groups
  -- left join: in case if data integrity fails:
  left join
    tblB ON groups.user=tblB.userid
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank:=0) AS init
```

-check your modified [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac600/2).

Comment: Please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887082/create-view-from-this-query .Thanks

Comment: how can I make the query you suggested into a view.

Comment: Not sure I got you. Please, ask separate question for new issue

Comment: yup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889081/create-a-view-which-gets-rank-username-and-count-of-user-records here

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do left join

```
SELECT
   groups.*,
 @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
 FROM
 (select 
user,
category,
count(*) as num,
tblB.username
from 
tblA
 left join tblB on tblA.id = tblB.userid
where 
category=1 
group by 
user, 
category
order by 
num desc,
user) AS groups
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank:=0) AS init
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac600/5)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery to do what you want.  You can simply join in the name:

```
  select username, category,
          count(*) as num,
          @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
  from tblA join
       tblB
       on tblA.user = tblB.userId CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT @rank:=0) AS cont
  where category = 1 
  group by username, category
  order by num desc, username;
```

`TblB` has an odd format.  Normally, the auto-incrementing id would be the "userid" for the table.

Also, because you are selecting only one category, strictly speaking it is unnecessary to put `category` in the `group by` statement.

EDIT:

You cannot create a view with this method of doing the `rank` because it uses variables.  It isn't easy to generate a rank on aggregated data in a view-compatible way in MySQL.

Comment: Hello Sir .I have tried the query you suggested but the response I get is 3 usernames but I should get 4 where category is 1 and also num column count shows all as 1 and not the count of users.

Comment: Also I need to convert the entire query to a view

Comment: Sir there is something wrong in the query you suggested.PLease check it out and let me know.Thanks

Comment: got it the tblA.id should be tblA.user sir and I tried to create to a view also the rank is wrong `SELECT username, category, count( * ) AS num, @rank := @rank +1 AS rank
FROM tblA
JOIN tblB ON tblA.user = tblB.userId
CROSS JOIN (

SELECT @rank :=0
) AS cont
WHERE category =1
GROUP BY username, category
ORDER BY num DESC , username`

Comment: added the table in q which shows table looks like.Please look into it .

Comment: Rank is still wrong .num is 6,2,2,1 and rank is 2,1,4,3

Comment: Maybe you do need the subquery in this case.  SQL Fiddle is down so I can't test it.

Comment: Oh Sure Sir .So what Alma DO suggested is right.COz its working .I thought your method would be much simpler .Also How do make this into a view.You had resolved a similar query before.

Comment: Please look into this Sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887082/create-view-from-this-query .Thanks

Comment: SQLFIddle is working now also sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887082/create-view-from-this-query please look into this .

Comment: Sir do you have any idea about how to create the query to view ........`SELECT
   groups.*,
 @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
 FROM
 (select 
user,
category,
count(*) as num,
tblB.username
from 
tblA
 left join tblB on tblA.id = tblB.userid
where 
category=1 
group by 
user, 
category
order by 
num desc,
user) AS groups
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank:=0) AS init`

Comment: is there any way to create view which  joins user id from tblB to user from tblA and returns username with rank ?

Comment: Your own query to create a view which satisfies the requirements.

Comment: new Q  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889081/create-a-view-which-gets-rank-username-and-count-of-user-records

Comment: how to convert this to view `SELECT username
    ,userid
    ,category
    ,Cnt
    ,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM (
            SELECT b.Username
                ,B.userid
                ,A.category
                ,count(*) Cnt
            FROM tblb B 
            JOIN tbla A
                ON B.UserID = A.User
            WHERE a.Category = 1
            GROUP BY b.username
        )a
,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r
Order by cnt desc`